# Unable to boot OS X after installing ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I installed ubuntu on my macbook air early 2014,but now I am unable to boot OSX after the installation of Ubuntu.
I used a USB flash drive to install
Ubuntu 15.10-amd64.ISO

When I press the 'power on' button,it boots to Ubuntu automatically
But if I press and hold 'alt' after pressing the 'power on' button it shows the Macintosh HD icon , when I press enter it shoes the Apple logo and then it shows a cross circle symbol.

Answer (score 0):

> When you see a circle with a slash symbol instead of the Apple logo, it means your Mac couldn't find a valid System Folder to start up from.
>   
> If you're using your Mac at a school or business, it might be trying to start from the [wrong version of OS X](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201686). Contact your IT department for more help. 
>   
> If this is your personal Mac, try reinstalling OS X by using [OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201314).

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156